# Remove rows with missing values in pandas

Tags: pandas, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe in which one of the columns has a few missing values.

The data frame consists of hundreds of rows, but in column 4, five of the values are `?`.

I want to remove the rows in which values are `?` in this column.

I have tried using something like

```
df = df[np.isfinite(df[:,4])]
```

Comment: Are they actually `?` (the string)? Do you want to remove the row if it contains any column as such?

Comment: Does the `DataFrame.dropna()` method achieve what you want to do?

Comment: `df[df.iloc[:,4].astype(str) != "?"]`. That is, if column 4 means index 4. Otherwise, you may want to use index 3 for column 4.

Answer (score 1):

To remove the rows for which the 4th column are equal to `?`, you can select the data that are not equal to `?`.

```
# Test data
df = DataFrame({
        'col0': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
        'col1': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
        'col2': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
        'col3': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
        'col4': [0, 1, 2, '?', '?']})

df.loc[df.iloc[:, 4] != '?']

   col0  col1  col2  col3 col4
0     0     0     0     0    0
1     1     1     1     1    1
2     2     2     2     2    2
```

If you want to eliminate the rows for which the 4th column contains `?`, it's a bit trickier since you have to escape the `?` character and provide a default value `False` for the boolean indexing to work and finally the boolean negation `~`.

```
df.loc[~df.iloc[:,4].str.contains('\?', na = False)]

   col0  col1  col2  col3 col4
0     0     0     0     0    0
1     1     1     1     1    1
2     2     2     2     2    2
```

## Edit

If the column contains only numbers, you can also use the following method. Converting to numeric using the `errors` parameter `coerce` in order to produce `NaN` for values that cannot be converting. Then simply dropping the values using `dropna`.

```
df.iloc[] = pd.to_numeric(df.iloc[:,4], errors='coerce')
# Or if you want to apply the transformation to the entire DataFrame
# df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')    
df.dropna(inplace=True)

      col0  col1  col2  col3  col4
0     0     0     0     0   0.0
1     1     1     1     1   1.0
2     2     2     2     2   2.0
```

Comment: Won't column 4 have all its numbers as string values after this because it had string values when it was loaded?

Comment: @Jamgreen Yes, I have just added an Edit to use this approach.